# Prevent double entry of tags in search by tags box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to prevent double entry of tags in a tag input box that I've made.

Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/4K6f7/5/

I'm trying to use two arrays to keep a check on which value is inside the box and which is inside drop down as such:

```
var array1 = ['PDF', 'Documents'];
var array2 = [];
```

where on click of an item from the drop down, it is removed from the array1 and put into array2. I'm not quite clear on the logic of it but I've tried my best to explain it in the fiddle.

The rest of the code is pretty straightforward for adding tags to the input box.

Is there a better way to do such a thing? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just simply hide from the dropdown the used tags

Comment: A small suggestion. Use descriptive names for your variables. Names like array1 and array2 are not clear as to what they are for. Start by giving them good clear names. Something like selectedTags.

Comment: (OT) ...do you really like the way your HTML looks with all those inline styles?

Comment: Also the only allowed child of an `ul` tag is a `li`. A `p` tag, or anything else is invalid html.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of neat jquery tag input plugins you could use. Such as this: http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hey man, the page i'm making isn't a pure website. It's for a Google Chrome attachment. The skeleton was made earlier by an outsourced firm and I was brought on board only in the third dev cycle. So, can't really change much. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick fix:

```
if(array2.indexOf(c) == -1) {
            array2.push(c);
            if (d != '') {
                ...
        }
```

and

```
$('#reset').click(function () {
    array2 = [];
    ....
```

Each time you add an item, you push it also to `array2`.
Then you test (`indexOf`) if the item is already in that array before adding it twice.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/4K6f7/8/)**

Comment: It works the first time, but the page breaks when you reset the tags.

Comment: @Newtt you are right! I've updated the Fiddle, array2 must be clean after a reset.